# How to write a desktop app that filters test questions according to topic

Tags: filter, desktop

What programming language/method would be best suited to writing a desktop app that
filters question types and displays a listing of those questions to view.

For example, if I have a mix algebra, geometry, and calculus questions stored in the app,
I should be able to select just the algebra questions to view and print.

I have a little experience with python/django but I've never made a desktop app before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lots of options. You will need to make several **design decisions** before you move forward. Things to consider are:

1. Which technologies do you feel comfortable with?
2. How much time/effort do you want to put into the project?
3. Are you willing to spend money on tools?
4. Etc.

That being said, the rest of this answer is to give you some **options to consider**:

1. You'll need a data structure which can filter the problems for you.
   From your description, the first thing I thought of was using a
   database, however I'm not sure if you are familar with databases, in
   which case you'd have to create some classes/structs that would allow for you to do the filtering yourself. Some options for databases are SQL Express, Oracle, MySQL, DB2, and many more.
2. Another thing to consider is you mentioned several different type of
   math problems. You'd want to consider how you would be displaying
   the problems. Mathematica formats math problems nicely, but if you
   wanted to go down this road, you'd either have to find a tool that
   would allow you to display that math problems in a syntax like
   Mathematica or do exports/screen shots of the problems and have those as
   part of your program.
3. Another option would be to try to find a
       language that has some sort of plugin for TeX or LaTeX (For example,
       you can see how wikipedia allows for nice math formatting here:
       http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula

This sounds like a good pet project to play with to learn different technologies. If that is the intent, great. If not, then you might want to do some googling to see if someone else has already created what you are looking for.